# Pointers, Vector Lists = Mass Confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector, dynamic-memory-allocation

*If you could suggest a more appropriate title I would be forever in your debt.*

The issue: I have a function which is recursive in nature, it aims to get each child from each quad and return it to the original caller. The problem is that I get the following every time I run the program (in my console window):

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I aim to retrieve each child as a pointer.

Here's the caller:

```
std::vector<Quad*> children = root->get_children_recursive(player_pos);
```

And here's the function itself:

```
std::vector<Quad*> Quad::get_children_recursive(glm::vec3 player_pos)  {
    std::vector<Quad*> out_children;

    if (children.size() != 0)  {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)  {
            Quad *child = &children[i];

            std::vector<Quad*> childs_children = child->get_children_recursive(player_pos);

            for (int j = 0; j < childs_children.size() - 1; j++)  {
                Quad *childs_child = childs_children.at(j);

                out_children.emplace_back(childs_child);
            }
        }
    }

    if (this->should_draw(player_pos))  {
        out_children.emplace_back(this);
    }

    return out_children;
}
```

If you would like me to supply more code or any other details I would be more than happy to oblige.

(every time I attempt to use the debugger and the program gets to the line that causes the aforementioned error I get a BSOD :O)

**Edit:**

Header:

```
class Quad  {
    public:
...
        std::vector<Quad*> get_children_recursive(glm::vec3 player_pos);
...
    protected:
    private:
...

        std::vector<Quad> children;
...
};
```

Comment: Since you are dealing with pointers here it makes no sense to use `emplace_back`.

Comment: Remember when you have a vector of pointers you need to call delete on each entry if you called new to add it to said vector. To stop memory leaks, but this is a memory access violation as described by Vasilev

Comment: Just a remark: filling the result per node is not very scalable.  It might be better to pass the result container by reference so it is filled only once.  Also, a std::deque might be a better fit if you can't guess the maximum usage of the result container.

Comment: @BjornPollex Why does it make no sense to use emplace_back? Please explain, I am new to c++. In addition, I never use 'new' on any vectors.

Comment: @Darestium: `emplace_back` is used to construct an object directly in the vector, as opposed to copying one (which is what `push_back` does). With pointers, the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Is children a `vector<Quad>` or `vector<Quad*>`? If it is `vector<Quad*>`, then this line is wrong:

```
Quad *child = &children[i];
```

because it will take the address of the pointer. Then

```
child->get_children_recursive(player_pos)
```

would most probably lead to the error you are getting.

To fix that, just remove the `&`.

Comment: Well, then that is not your problem. We need to look somewhere else.

Comment: Any other ideas? I am stumped.

Comment: Which exactly is the line that causes the program to crash?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < childs_children.size() - 1; j++)  {
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < childs_children.size(); j++)  {
```